# Does $\varphi(x)\le\int_0^x\varphi(t)dt$ for all $x\in[0,\infty)$ imply $\varphi\equiv0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Let $\varphi$ be a nonnegative and continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ and such that $$\varphi(x)\le\int_0^x\varphi(t)dt$$ for all $x\in[0,\infty)$. Can we infer from here that $\varphi\equiv0$.

By taking limit on both sides, I got $\varphi(0)\le 0$. As $\varphi$ is nonnegative, I can say $\varphi(0)=0$. But what then. I could have progressed if I could show that $\varphi(x)\le \varphi'(x)$, but it is not quite evident from the given condition.

Comment: How did you get this function? Intuition?

Comment: Actually its not true $\int_0^x(e^t-1)dt=e^x-x-1\le e^x-1$. Hence $\varphi(x)=e^x-1$ doesnt satisfy the condition

Comment: sorry, my previous comment was not true, observe the it would imply that $e^x-1\le e^x-x\implies -1\le -x$ what doesnt necessarily holds on $[0,\infty)$. By the Gronwall lemma your assertion is true, that is, $\varphi=0$.

Comment: Yeahm already did that, But I didnt know about Gronwall lemma, so I read it up. But still the lemma only implies $\varphi(x)\le e^x$

Comment: using the mean value theorem you can try to show that $\varphi(x)\le\varphi(\xi)x$ for all $x\in[0,\infty)$ for some $\xi\in[0,x]$ cannot be possible.

Comment: Ican't work it out myself. Can you give a detailed answer. Please.

Comment: This is literally just an application of Gronwall's lemma. You can find a proof of it many places.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The usual technique is to consider $$g(x) =e^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}\varphi(t)\,dt$$ and then $$g'(x) =e^{-x} \left(\varphi(x) - \int_{0}^{x}\varphi(t)\,dt\right)\leq 0$$ so that $g$ is decreasing and hence $g(x) \leq g(0)=0$. But $g$ is non-negative and hence $g(x) =0$ for all $x\geq 0$ and therefore $\int_{0}^{x}\varphi(t)\,dt=e^{x} g(x) $ and it's derivative $\varphi(x)$ vanish for all $x\geq 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $\varphi$ on the interval $[0,1]$. Then by the Extreme Value Theorem $\varphi$ has a maximum value on it and assume it attains it for $M \in [0,1]$. Then by the condition we have:

$$\varphi(M) \le \int_0^M \varphi(x) dx  \le \int_0^M \varphi(M) dx = \varphi(M) \cdot M$$

If $M=1$ then from the obtained equality in we get that $\varphi(x) = \varphi(M)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, but this gives us that $\varphi(x) = \varphi(0) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Otherwise if $M \in [0,1)$ we have that $\varphi(M) = 0$ and as $0 = \varphi(M) \ge \varphi(x) \ge 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$ we have that $\varphi(x) = 0$ on $[0,1]$

Now similarly consider $\varphi$ on $[1,2]$. It has a maximum value $N$. Then by the condition:

$$\varphi(N) \le \int_0^N \varphi(x) dx  = \int_1^N \varphi(M) dx = \varphi(N) \cdot (N-1) \implies \varphi(N) = 0$$

Here we used the fact that $\int_0^1 \varphi(x) dx = 0$ and that $N-1 \le 1$ with similar arguement as above.

Therefore going by a interval of a length $1$ at a time we can prove that $\varphi(x) = 0 $ on $[0, \infty)$

Comment: yep, beautiful and easier that what I tried.

Comment: @Masacroso Funny how the answers kept improving from yours, to mine, to Singh's

Comment: That's the beauty of MSE. In minutes you can get a sequence of better and even better answers.

Answer (score 2):

Using the MVT we can rewrite the inequality as

$$\varphi(x)\le \varphi(\xi)x,\quad\forall x\in[0,\infty)\tag1$$

for some $\xi\in[0,x]$. Then:

1. If $x< 1$ and $\varphi(x)\neq 0$, then by the continuity and non-negativity of $\varphi$ we have that

   $$0<\varphi(x)/x\le\varphi(\xi_1)\implies \varphi(\xi_1)/\xi_1\le\varphi(\xi_2)\implies\cdots\implies\varphi(\xi_k)/\xi_k\le\varphi(\xi_{k+1})$$

   Thus observe that the sequence defined by $(\xi_k)$ is decreasing and bounded below by zero so it converges to some point in $[0,1]$. Hence applying limits to both sides of $\varphi(\xi_k)/\xi_k\le\varphi(\xi_{k+1})$ we find that

   $$\begin{matrix}\infty\le\varphi(0),\quad\text{whenever }\lim\xi_k= 0\\\text{or}\quad\varphi(c)/c\le\varphi(c),\quad\text{whenever }\lim \xi_k=c>0\end{matrix}$$

   In any case we reach a contradiction so we conclude that $\varphi(x)=0$ when $x\in[0,1)$.
2. Assume, from the previous part, that $\varphi(x)=0$ for $x\in[0,1)$. Then, by continuity, $\varphi(1)=0$ also. Suppose now that $\varphi(x)>0$ for some $x\in(1,2)$. Then the original inequality implies

   $$\varphi(x)\le\int_1^x\varphi(t)\,\mathrm dt\implies\varphi(x)=(x-1)\varphi(\xi),\quad\forall x\in[1,2)\tag2$$

   for some $\xi\in[1,x]$. Thus repeating the same recursion than in the previous part we have that

   $$\begin{matrix}\infty\le\varphi(1),\quad\text{whenever }\lim\xi_k= 1\\\text{or}\quad\varphi(c)/(c-1)\le\varphi(c),\quad\text{whenever }\lim \xi_k=c>1\end{matrix}$$

   In any case we find that necessarily $\varphi=0$ also in $[1,2)$.
3. Finally, by the previous cases, using strong induction on the intervals $[k,k+1)$ it can be shown that $\varphi=0$ for all $x\in[0,\infty)$, as desired.

---

For sake of completion I will add a simple version of the Gronwall's lemma that I know from *Analysis II* of Amann and Escher:

> Consider a non-empty interval $J$, $t_0\in J$, $\alpha,\beta\in[0,\infty)$ and a continuous function $y:J\to[0,\infty)$ that satisfies
>
> $$y(t)\le\alpha+\beta\left|\int_{t_0}^ty(s)\,\mathrm ds\right|,\quad\forall t\in J$$
>
> then $$y(t)\le\alpha e^{\beta|t-t_0|},\quad\forall t\in J$$

Then applying this theorem to the exercise we can see that $\alpha=0$, consequently $\varphi=0$.

Comment: @Shalop doyou know a simpler proof?

Comment: Sorry, you are right that $\varphi$ does not need to be differentiable. But your proof is still incorrectly written: in item 2, the limit obviously cannot depend on $k$. Moreover, parts of the argument could use clarification. @AbishankaSaha The proof may be simplified by using continuity to bound $\varphi$ by $C$ on $[0,x]$, and then proving inductively that $\varphi(t) \leq Ct^n/n!$, for all $n$.

Comment: why you says that the limit doesnt depends on $k$? Clearly $\xi_k$ define a decreasing and bounded sequence, so it limit is well-defined. Ok, I corrected something that was wrong.

Comment: There are still some problems, for example it is not true that $\varphi(c)/c=\varphi(c)$ in item 1. You can only conclude that $\varphi(c)/c \leq \varphi(c)$ (which is enough) since $\varphi(\xi_k)/\xi_k \leq \varphi(\xi_{k+1})$ (also, you should clarify the fact that $\xi_k$ is defined inductively and converges to a limit because it is decreasing by construction). Similarly in item 2, you can only derive a contradiction if $x \in (1,2]$, since you get $\varphi(c)/(c-1) \leq \varphi(c)$. Then you have to keep going one interval at a time, just like in the proof by Stefan4024.

Comment: @Shalop, yes, you are right. I think I definitely fixed it.

Comment: Now it looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

By Grönwall's inequality (integral form), 
$$
\varphi(x) \leq \int_0^x \varphi(t) dt \implies \varphi(x) \leq 0,
$$
thus $\varphi \equiv 0$.

Comment: Maybe a link or something to this version of the Grönwall's inequality could be useful.

Comment: But $\varphi$ isn't assumed to be differentiable.

Comment: @Stefan4024 Gronwall's inequality holds for MUCH more than just differentiable functions. See [Theorem 2 here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Gronwall_lemma).

Comment: @Shalop I might admit it's the first time I've come across the Gronwall's Inequality, so a quick Google search caused me to say this. Nevertheless in the theorem you sent me it says that $\varphi$ must be bounded. Can we be sure of it?

Comment: @Stefan4024 It has to be bounded on intervals of finite length, which holds in this case by continuity.

Comment: @Shalop You maybe right. As I've said it's the first time I come across this inequality, so I might need to analyze it better.

Comment: @Stefan4024 for sake of completion I had added a simple version of the Gronwall lemma to my answer (the proof can be found in the book where I get it).