# Let $A$ be a set of all continuous functions $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R^+ \cup \{0\}$ that satisfies the following condition.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, continuity

> Let $A$ be a set of all continuous functions $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R^+
> \cup \{0\}$ that satisfies the following condition:
>
> $$\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt \ge f(x), \forall x\in [0,1].$$
>
> Which of the following statements is true?
>
> (A)  $A$ has cardinality $1$.
>
> (B) $A$ has cardinality $2$.
>
> (C) $A$ is infinite.
>
> (D) $A=\phi$

**Case 1**

$\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt =f(x)$, differentiating on both the sides. We get, $f'(x)=f(x)\implies f(x)=Ke^{x}$. hence option (C) is correct. Am I correct? Please check my steps. how it is wrong?

Comment: $f(x) =0$ identically and hence $A$ is correct.

Comment: @paramanand Sing Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2536328/72031

Comment: You have replaced inequality with equality. Even with equality you have not done it correctly.

Comment: Your $f(x)=Ke^x$ does not obey $\int_0^x\ge f(x)$ for tiny $x$, such as $0\ge f(0)$ in the limit.

Comment: but it is less than or equall to no?

Comment: Even if you try with equality you will get $f(x) =0$. For your solution $K=0$ is the only possibility.

Answer (score 4):

You are wrong, because the function $Ke^x\not \in A$ with $K>0$: for  $x\in [0,1]$,
$$\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=K(e^x-1) \not\ge Ke^x=f(x).$$
Let $f\in A$. Since $f$ is continuous and non negative, it has a maximum value $M\geq 0$. Then for  $x\in [0,1]$,
$$Mx=\int_{0}^{x}Mdt\geq \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt \ge f(x).$$
Using the upper bound again, we have that for  $x\in [0,1]$,
$$\frac{Mx^2}{2}=\int_{0}^{x}Mtdt\geq \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt \ge f(x).$$
Show by induction that for any positive integer $n$, for $x\in [0,1]$,
$$\frac{Mx^n}{n!} \ge f(x).$$
What may we conclude about the non-negative function $f$?
What is the cardinality of $A$?

Comment: I understood your steps. But not able to draw the conclusion that, $f(x)=0$. I can draw $f(0)=0$ from this. Can you please give hint?

Comment: For $Mx^n/n!\to 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, $$F(x)=e^{-x}\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$$
Show that $F$ is monotone decreasing !

So, $F(x)\le F(0)$. That's done !